# Freemarker function string formattting

Tags: freemarker

I have the issue related to string formatting in a function of the freemarker. Let's admit there is the next function:

```
<#function transformWithSign sign amount>
<#--<#local str = amount?string["########.00"]>-->
    <#local str = amount?string>
    <#local str += sign?string>
    <#return str>
</#function>
```

So, the commented out line does not work and appears the error is "*freemarker.core.NonMethodException: For "...(...)" callee: Expected a method or function, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):
==> amount?string  [in template "html/invoiceTemplate.ftlh" at line 52, column 23]*"

This row works fine:

```
<#local str = amount?string>
```

What is wrong there? Or does the freemarker function not work with string formatting?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `amount` is not a number, but a string that looks like a number. Thus, `amount?string` will just return the original string as is, and that string doesn't support the `[]` or `()` operators. If `amount` was a number (or date, or boolean), then `?string` returns a more fancy string that does support those operators.

To demonstrate the problem:

```
<#assign amount = 123>
<#-- Works: -->
${amount?string}
<#-- Also works: -->
${amount?string["########.00"]}
```

But (note the quotation marks around 123):

```
<#assign amount = "123">
<#-- Works: -->
${amount?string}
<#-- FAILS: -->
${amount?string["########.00"]}
```

Ideally, you should ensure that `amount` comes as a number. But, you can also ask FreeMarker to convert it if it's a string, although, be sure that the string in `amount` uses the typical computer language number format (not some localized format):

```
${amount?number?string["########.00"]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ddekany, was changed to formatting an input value as amount?number while the amount pass to func, and it works as expected!

Comment: @DmitriiVashchenko Then you are supposed to Accept this answer.